# An alphametic division of all different digits

Tags: mathematics, alphametic

Here is a division process: ABCD / PQ = XYZ with remainder R.

The ten letters A,B,C,D,P,Q,X,Y,Z,R are all different digits.

[image: ABCD / PQ = XYZ ... R]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With just a little bit of case-bashing, I've found there to be just one solution

> $$A,B,C,D,P,Q,R,X,Y,Z = 8,3,6,0,1,4,2,5,9,7$$ that is $$PQ = 14, XYZ = 597, ABCD = 8360, R=2$$

Reasoning

> The last computation gives that the difference between a three-digit number and a two-digit number is a 1-digit number. This means that the three-digit number here must begin with $10$ and the two-digit number must begin with $9$. This tells us that $PQ$ must divide into a number strictly between $90$ and $100$. Furthermore, $PQ$ cannot itself be in the nineties because it is less than $AB$ by a two-digit number. If we assume no leading zeroes, this gives the following possibilities for $PQ$ - $12, 13, 14, 19, 23, 46, 47, 48, 49$ (note that $31$ and $32$ are disallowed because we would have $Z=3=P$, $24$ is disallowed because we would have $Z=4$ and $16$ is disallowed because $Z=6$). 
>  If $PQ$ is in the forties, then we must have $Z=2$ and since $PQ \times X < AB$, it must be that $X=1$.
>  Since $Y>2$ (the second division computation assures $Y$ non-zero) and cannot be equal to $P$ or $Q$, this leaves five possibilities for $XYZ$ to check for each number in the forties, which can be quickly done by hand.
>  In summary, we get that either $A$ or $B$ will always be equal to one of $P,Q,X,Y,Z$ or equal to each other. There are a few simplifications that can be done here. For example, $Y=8$ forces $A=8$ so is disallowed immediately but case-bashing is quick enough. Hence, there are no solutions for $PQ$ in the forties which leaves five possibilities for $PQ$.
>  $PQ=23$ means that $Z=4$ and since $PQ \times X < AB$ then $X$ must be $1$.
>  $23 \times 194 < 5000$ so there is no way to pick $Y$ so that $A > 4$ hence no solutions.
>  $PQ=19$ means that $Z=5$ and $X$ can be $2,3$ or $4$.
>  If $X=2$ then $Y > 5$ means that $A=5$ so we must have $Y=3,4$. However a quick check shows that neither work.
>  If $X=3$, there are five cases to check for $Y$ but non work because $A$ or $B$ is equal to one of $P,Q,X,Y,Z$.
>  If $X=4$ then $Y>6$ forces $A=9=Q$ so we just have three cases to check for $XYZ$.
>  In this instance, we get close twice
>  $425 \times 19 = 8075$ which leaves a possibility for $ABCD$ as $8076$ but means $R=1=P$.
>  $435 \times 19 = 8265$ which leaves a possibility for $ABCD$ as $8267$ but means $R=2=B$. The other possibility for $Y$ leaves $A=B$ so there are no solutions here.
>  If $PQ=14$ then $Z=7$ and $X < 7$ which gives four possibilities for $X$.
>  If $X=2$, then $Y > 7$ puts $A=4=Q$ so that leaves three possibilities for $XYZ$ which can be done by hand, but none work.
>  If $X=3$, then $Y<6$ puts $A=4=Q$ so there are three possibilities to check for $XYZ$ but none work.
>  If $X=5$ then $Y<7$ puts $A=7=Z$ so there are two possibilities to check for $XYZ$. $587$ gives $A=8=Y$ but $597 \times 14 = 8358$ which allows $ABCD = 8360$ and $R=2$ and **this is a valid solution** $$A,B,C,D,P,Q,R,X,Y,Z = 8,3,6,0,1,4,2,5,9,7$$ If $X=6$ then there are five cases to check for $Y$. One that comes close is $XYZ = 637$  which puts $637 \times 14 = 8918$ which allows $ABCD = 8920$ but puts $R=2=C$. Another which comes close is $657 \times 14 = 9198$ which allows $ABCD = 9203$ but then $R=5=Y$. None of the other possibilities work.
>  If $PQ=13$ then $Z=7$ and notice that the last computation has a $91$ which would force $D=0$ and $R=9$. Since $X < 7$ there are then four possibilities for $X$.
>  $X=2$ forces $A=3=Q$ so that won't work.
>  $X=4$ gives four possibilities for $Y$ but none work because of the values of $A$ and $B$.
>  If $X=5$ then $XYZ=527$ is a close solution but puts $A=C=6$. Otherwise $Y>3$ forces $A=7=Z$ so there are no solutions here.
>  If $X=6$ then there are four possibilities for $XYZ$ but in each case the value of $B$ clashes with one of the previously chosen values.
>  If $PQ=12$ then $Z=8$ and $X<8$ which leaves five possibilities for $X$.
>  If $X=3$ then there are five possibilities for $XYZ$.
>  $Y=7$ gives the close solution $12 \times 378 = 4536$ but then $C=X$ or $C=A$.
>  Also $Y=9$ gives $12 \times 398 = 4776$ but means $C=B$ or $C=Z$ so no solution here either.
>  If $X=4$ then $B$ clashes with one of the values already chosen so there are no solutions.
>  If $X=5$ then there are five possibilities for $Y$.
>  $Y=3$ gives $12 \times 538 = 6456$ which is close but forces $C=X$ or $C=A$.
>  Also $Y=7$ gives $12 \times 578 = 6936$ which allows $ABCD=6940$ but then $R=4=C$ (rather than $3$ so this is *really* close).
>  Other values of $Y$ force $B$ to clash with one of the previously chosen values.
>  If $X=6$ then $Y>5$ forces $A=8=Z$ so there are just three possibilities for $Y$ to check here but in each case $B$ clashes with one of the previously chosen values.
>  If $X=7$ then $Y<5$ forces $A=8=Z$ so there are just three possibilities for $Y$ to check here. The only one which is close is $Y=5$ which gives $12 \times 758 = 9096$ but then $C=A$ or $B=1=P$ so this doesn't work.
>  Hence there is just one solution

Here is how the division progresses

> [image]

Comment: I wrote an exhaustive program which found 29 solutions. I then thought the empty squares in the diagram must have one digit in each – with a unique solution that can be obtained logically – but it's impossible to obtain a 2-digit number from the first division.

Comment: @WeatherVane Hopefully this has cleared things up?

Comment: I don't get where the first row of the division come from: I make it $5$. The most the quotient in the first line can be is $98 / 10$ which is $9$, a single digit.

Comment: @WeatherVane $PQ=14$, $X=5$ so $PQ \times X = 70$ which is the highest multiple of $PQ$ less than $AB=83$

Comment: Oh yes, brain fart here. I might have got there but for that! I'll revist my solution.